# Why aren't unreferenced symbols not optimized out by default?

Tags: c

I realize there are ways to remove unreferenced symbols from the final binary by passing flags to the compiler and linker, but why doesn't this happen by default (static linking)?

Comment: What do you mean by “default linking”? Does it provide debug or optimised executable? Different use cases require different options.

Comment: The "*final binary*" could be a library where the "*unreferenced symbols*" are in fact the public APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are some traditional practices that depend on unreferenced variables staying in the binary.

In particular, it has been common to declare a global string containing special sequences that are replaced by the version control system, e.g. something like this:

```
static char sccsid[] = "@(#)ls.c        8.1 (Berkeley) 6/11/93";
```

Comment: I found a discussion thread from 13 years ago when gcc started removing unused strings ... did they revert that decision?

Answer (score 1):

Standard(*) linking semantics for static libraries are that exactly those object files from an archive (static library) which are needed to resolve undefined symbols get pulled into the link, as if they were object files listed on the link command line. So, as long as you factor your libraries into indepedent translation units (and thus object files) well, unreferenced symbols "are optimized out" already, by never being pulled in to begin with.

If you want finer-grained optimizing-out, you need to leave the object files in a form where this is possible. Traditionally, object files contain a single text section for all code and a single data section for all data, and these are *already flattened* in a way that individual functions or data objects can't be subsequently removed. Modern tooling optionally supports using a separate section per function or data object, which the linker can then use for fine-grained dropping of unreferenced sections via `--gc-sections`. Arguably this should be default nowadays, but it does break certain custom linking setups using explicit placement of code or objects into sections without explicit referencing, which is probably the reason why it's still not default.

---

(*) Here "standard" is outside the scope of the C language standard, and is a matter of how the Unix-derived C language tooling has always worked and been specified (roughly equivalently) in various places like SysV, ELF, etc.